# Why is the React state not being updated properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, javascript-objects

I'm making a math game, and I'd like the range of the operands to be updated after a certain amount of questions. I have this code to set the difficulty

```
  const [difficulty, setDiff] = useState({rangeA:[1, 10], rangeB:[1, 10]});
  
  function setDifficulty(op) {
    let rangeA = [];
    let rangeB = [];
    if (question < 5) { //question state is incremented everytime the answer is correct, which triggers the next question
      rangeA = [0, 100];
      rangeB = [0, 10];
    }
    else if (question < 8) {
      rangeA = [0, 100];
      rangeB = [0, 100];
    }
    setDiff({...difficulty, rangeA, rangeB});
    console.log(rangeB, difficulty.rangeB); // when question is 5, this logs [0, 100] [0, 10], but they should be the same value [0,100]
  }
```

but the state doesn't update properly, what could be happening?

Comment: setDiff is async so its effect is not immediate
``` useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(difficulty);
},[difficulty]}
```
add this

Comment: @vatsalsoni Thanks, that was helpful. Would you know if I used useReducer I'd have the same problem? I mean, is useReducer async as well? My code is having a lot of different useStates, so I'm considering to switch to useReducer.

Comment: You can use React Developer Tools extension to track complicated states, it's more reliable than `console.log()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(difficulty)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [difficulty])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "difficulty" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setDiff`, the new value of `difficulty` will be updated during the next render.
Since you are `console.log`ging inside the `setDifficulty` function, before the render occurred, the reference to `difficulty.rangeB` still holds the value before the update.